# JS Beautifier for Visual Studio Code - How to keep comments on their own lines

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have VSCode 1.20.1 installed with [Beautify by michelemelluso](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify). When we format LESS files, how do we keep `//` comments on their own lines rather than bumping up to previous lines. The following happens in my LESS files...

**unformatted**

```
.demoa {
text-align:left;
}
//Comment
.demob {
text-align:right;
}
```

**formated**

```
.demoa {
text-align:left;
}//Comment
.demob {
text-align:right;
}
```

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Are you using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=michelemelluso.code-beautifier? I don't get your result with your exact code above, however if I add a space before the //Comment then I get your result.  It seems very brittle.

Comment: Thanks,  my code example is probably not the best but I am glad you see the result I am facing.  There has to be a setting in either vscode settings or Beautify that allows line breaking control for comments when we format...I just haven't found it...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Try adding the following settings to your .jsbeautifyrc file and see if it works:

`"max_preserve_newlines": 10,
"preserve_newlines": true,`